# How to display ACF coustom field from category on author.php

Tags: plugins, author

I use ACF added a coustom field for category.

it works fine in archive.php , here is code:

```
<?php echo get_field('students_no_class', get_queried_object() );?>
```

but it doesn’t work in author.php , nothing show up.

in author page I need disaply coustom field value after

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
```

I also did a test:when I delete author.php, the author page will use archive.php template and the coustom field show up nothing.

Comment: can you please add screenshots of acf field, author.php code and category.php file code so can clearly understand about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ACF for Authors, you need to supply the author in `'user_'.$user_id` format.

Which would be this:

```
echo get_field( 'students_no_class', 'user_'. get_queried_object()->ID );
```

or this:

```
the_field( 'students_no_class', 'user_'. get_queried_object()->ID );
```